# Unable to halt at breakpoints when debugging using "Attach to Node Functions" in VSCode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger

## Problem Description

- When debugging Azure Functions in VSCode using the Attach to Node Functions option, Functions run but I am unable to halt execution at any breakpoints.
- This behaviour is new. Debugging worked correctly until a few days ago. I do not remember changing any settings or launch.json in the meantime.
- Azure Functions Core Tools cli outputs "Debugger Attached"

## What I tried

- Uninstall/reinstall Azure Functions Core Tools
- Uninstall/reinstall node
- Try different versions of node
- Ensure launch.json has not been edited since the last time debugging worked
- Create a new Azure Functions App to test - receive same results
- Ensure breakpoints are activated and locked in

I'm really at a loss as I believe I did not make any changes recently regarding debugging configuration.

Comment: Did you check if you are building in debug mode and check if you have the pdb file and it is updated when you build.

Comment: I do not have a pdb file, but I also haven't had one in the past when debugging was working correctly. 

How can I check to see I am building in debug mode? I use Ctrl + F5 which activated the following configuration in my launch.json:    


    {
      "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9229,
      "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
    },

Comment: Actually that might not be relevant for Node. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a default port for `Nodejs` and the `Azure Function` debugging always uses (**port 9229**).

By default the extension host process is not listening for the inspect protocol (so no inspect port is open by default). To enter inspect mode VS Code sends signal `SIGUSR1` to the extension host process which will open the default inspect port `9229`.

Probably it may cause the issue. You can use some other port instead of `9229`.

If you're running into this while debugging Azure Functions, the workaround is to update the debug port to something other than 9229 in your `.vscode/launch.json`.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Attach to Node Functions",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach", 
            "port": 19229,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ] 
}
```

Refer [here for similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85328)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this fix did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried changing the port 9229 instead of your own port number. Some are facing the similar [Issue with vscode ](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73818) please see[Debugging -  Node.js ](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) still having issue please raise a support ticket [New support request](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview)